# How do I get the name of the two active Twitter bootstrap tabs?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of twitter bootstrap tabs that are rendered like so:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="models">
        <ul id="model-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a href="#model_1" data-toggle="tab">Model 1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#model_2" data-toggle="tab">Model 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="modelTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="model_1"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="model_2">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="firmware">
                        <ul id="firmware-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                           <li class="active"><a href="#fw_1'" data-toggle="tab">FW 1</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#fw_2'" data-toggle="tab">FW 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I get the names of the active tabs? In this case Model 2 => FW 1

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the active tabs, you can search for active li elements:

```
 $('li.active')
```

This will return a list of li elements. Here's an example that gets the active tabs and logs the names:

```
$('li.active').each(function(index) {
   console.log($(this).find('a').html());       
});
```

Which would result in:

> ```
> Model 2
> FW 1
> ```